# WebException error 404 after upgrading NServiceBus to version 3.3.8

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I just updated my NServiceBus solution to version 3.3.8.  My previous version was 3.2.2.

When I run my solution, I receive the following error:

WebException Occurred
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

System.Net.WebException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadStringInternal(Func`1 getResponse) in 
    c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 279
  InnerException:

From Visual Studio:
Locating source for 'c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ReplicationInformer.cs'. (No checksum.)
The file 'c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ReplicationInformer.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ReplicationInformer.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ReplicationInformer.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: 
    c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ReplicationInformer.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ReplicationInformer.cs'.

I have tried updating to build 992 for RavenDB. (Stopped RavenDB, and replaced binaries for the exe) 
I removed RavenDB completely, and used NServiceBus.Host.exe /InstallInfrastructure in an attempt to reinstall RavenDB.
This failed to resolve the issue.

I have also read that this is a typical WebException for NServiceBus version 3.3.x?  Do I need to suppress the exception for Visual Studio debugging?

Here is my bus configuration:

```
        Bus = NServiceBus.Configure.With()
            .DefineEndpointName("Orders")
            .Log4Net()
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport()
                .IsTransactional(false)
                .PurgeOnStartup(false)
            .UnicastBus()
                .LoadMessageHandlers()
                .ImpersonateSender(false)
            .CreateBus()
            .Start();
```

Here is my endpoint configuration:

```
  public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server
  {
  }
```

Here is my app.config:

```
 <configuration>
 <configSections>
   <section name="MsmqTransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqTransportConfig,  NServiceBus.Core" />
   <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
   <section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
 </configSections>
 <MsmqTransportConfig ErrorQueue="error" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5" />
 <UnicastBusConfig ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="">
   <MessageEndpointMappings>
     <add Messages="InternalMessages" Endpoint="Manager" />
   </MessageEndpointMappings>
 </UnicastBusConfig>
 <MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" />
 </configuration>
```

Do I need to manually configure NServiceBus to connect to RavenDB?  If so, how? My solution worked great with NServiceBus version 3.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to disable break on all exceptions.

Comment: I disabled System.Net.WebException in visual studio. (Debug - Exceptions - CLR exceptions - System.net.WebException) This disabled the exception break. Thanks for your help. My application runs great in debug mode. I would like to know what causes the exception. NServiceBus is making a call to RavenDB in this case.  Why? Can the call be blocked via NServiceBus configuration?

Comment: The exception you seeing is because RavenDB by default has replication turned on, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869700/how-to-disable-ravendb-replication