# NServiceBus throws The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: nservicebus

I use simple a configuration to run a Publish/Subscribe scenario using NServiceBus.

I'm getting this exception:

```
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadJsonInternal(Func`1 getResponse) in
   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 332
```

It's not a fatal one, it's handled somewhere in NServiceBus/RavenDb code, but I wonder why it's happening. I see it only when I select "Thrown" option for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" in Exceptions window.

Comment: hi see the comment John Simons made in this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966570/webexception-error-404-after-upgrading-nservicebus-to-version-3-3-8
which follows into this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869700/how-to-disable-ravendb-replication. The problem though this is REALLY annonying, we have 4 web projects that constantly need to be "continued". I don't want to disabled System.Net.WebException as we use httpserver also. I tried a [DebuggerNonUserCode] but that doesn't help. Am also really curious if this can be fixed/stopped

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding Log4Net (easiest is through the Visual Studio Package manager), and then telling NServiceBus that it should use log4net when configuring the Bus:

```
Bus = Configure.With()
    .Log4Net()
    .DefaultBuilder() //...
```

You'll find that NServiceBus logs plenty (either to the Console window of the NServiceBus host, or to the Visual Studio debugger window), and it's very likely to contain the reason why that 404 occurs.

Comment: I did configure NservieBus to output all logs to the console but this exception is never logged. It's handled internally in RavenDB.