# Make RavenDB stop looking for replication

Tags: exception, replication, ravendb, nservicebus

I’m using NServiceBus 3.6.1 with RavenDB 2.0.2375.

While starting it I get the following:

Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

I'm using Visual Studio and I like to have the Common Language Runtime Exceptions row ticked (to break when an exception is thrown), as it is very useful to trace the source of all exceptions in my code, but because RavenDB throws and catches internally these exceptions I’m being prompted 20 times with the same exception.
I heard this is due to RavenDB replication and I looked at my Raven.Server.exe.config and the replication looks disabled. So I don’t know what’s this exception about…

How can I tell RavenDB to not look for replication databases, since I'm not using it (this would stop with these internally handled exceptions)?

Thanks

PS: More info:

Got also this error message: "ReplicationInformer.cs not found" when VS was trying to disassemble the code, so it looks it is really about replication.

Second Exception:
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in Raven.Client.Lightweight
Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

**Edit:**

Related to this thread: [NServiceBus throws The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676908/nservicebus-throws-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-404-not-found)

**Edit2:**
Maybe this can be considered a Visual Studio bug, since I have the option "Just my code" ticked, so it showdn't break on nuget packages exceptions?